# How to rewrite/replace xml.gz file's content using nginx substitutions4nginx module

Tags: xml, nginx, reverse-proxy, substitution

I am using `nginx` `substitutions4nginx` module for `reverse proxying` in nginx.

And I am trying to replace few occurrences of string with another string.

Current configuration looks like this:

```
server {
server_name  proxy-example.com;
    access_log  /dev/null;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://example.com;

proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding ""; 
proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;   
proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

subs_filter_types text/html text/javascript text/plain text/css text/xml;
subs_filter 'example.com' "proxy-example.com";

    }
}
```

Using this configuration , text gets replace from `.css`, `.txt`, `.xml` files but not from `.xml.gz` files.

---

I have tried adding `application/x-gzip` in `subs_filter_types` like this:

```
subs_filter_types text/html text/javascript text/plain text/css text/xml application/x-gzip;
```

Also tried using:

```
subs_filter_types text/html * ;
```

But still text inside `.xml.gz` file doesnt gets replaced.

What am I doing wrong ?
I am trying to replace `example.com` with `proxy-example.com` in

```
example.com/file.xml.gz
```

ref: https://code.google.com/archive/p/substitutions4nginx/

Comment: How are you going to replace content in a gzipped stream? You probably should enable `gunzip` option first to decompress proxied response first.

Answer (score 0):

gzip is not supported, from nginx documentation:

> This module can be compatible with gzip filter module. But it will not work with proxy compressed response.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/